# vertical text orientation in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, styles

I have a text, is written vertically with the writing-mode:tb-lr; property, but does not work in IE7, texts are horizontally, how do I the same behave in all browsers?

```
.haccordion li div .accordion_content_indicator p {
    width: 200px;
    height: 210px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #8a8890;
    font-family: "Arial Narrow";
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    writing-mode:tb-lr;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531187(v=vs.85).aspx), not at all: `tb-lr - 
Windows Internet Explorer 8. Content flows vertically from top to bottom, left to right. [...]` No idea whether a workaround exists - there may not be one

Answer (score 1):

Vertical Text in Internet Explorer 8 and Below

http://www.aquim.com/web-article-226.html

Comment: thanks for the link.... the problem was with other element of my page, excuse me for my silly question